# Why are some of my Cloudant documents not being indexed when using Cloudant Search?

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

I have a number of documents like this:

```js
{ 
  "name": "Fred",
  "email": "fred@aol.com"
}
```

And I index them using Cloudant Search with an index function like this:

```js
function(doc) {
  index("name", doc.name)
  index("email", doc.email)
}
```

In some cases, queries for an email address that exists in my database returns nothing. e.g. this document is not returned for a search `q=email:bob@aol.com`:

```js
{ 
  "email": "bob@aol.com",
  "provisional": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When indexing data using Cloudant Search, it's important not to index `undefined` values. So your document:

```js
{ 
  "email": "bob@aol.com",
  "provisional": true
}
```

has a missing `name` attribute, but your index document is attempting to index the missing `name` field - this will produce an error and **no fields from that document will make it into the index**. This is why searches on the document's email field fail.

The solution is to add "guard clauses" into your index function:

```js
function(doc) {
  if (doc.name) {
    index("name", doc.name)
  }
  if (doc.email) {
    index("email", doc.email)
  }
}
```

The "if" statements around each "index" function call will ensure that even if a field is missing from a document, it won't attempt to index an `undefined` value.

For more information on guard clauses, see the [Cloudant documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-cloudant-search#index-guard-clauses).